product inequalities solution
Fix $k$ and $n$ positive integers. Then, denote by $A_k$ by the following:
$$A_k=\{x>0:\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k(\frac{n}{2}-x+j)}{\prod_{j=1}^k(n+j)}<\frac{
1}{2^k}\}$$
Is there a way to show that $inf A_k$ increases as k increases? Been trying to analyze this for a personal problem... Any thoughts on this helps a lot
As a clarification, suppose k=1. Then, we have $A_1$ is all values $x>0$ such that $\frac{n/2+1-x}{n+1}<\frac{1}{2}\iff x>0.5$, thus, $A_1=(0.5,\infty)$ and $inf A_1=0.5$. Then ideally, I'd like that for $k=2$,the ""smallest"" solution increases, and so on...

Some thoughts.
Remark. Some parts are not rigorous.
For example, the digamma function is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$.
I simply look at the figure. A rigorous proof is required.
Let us prove that, for fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2}$, it holds that $\inf A_1 < \inf A_2 < \cdots < \inf A_n$.
First, we prove that $\inf A_k \le \frac{k}{2}$ for all $1\le k \le n$. It suffices to prove that, for all $2\le k \le n$,
$$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k \left(\frac{n}{2} - \frac{k}{2} + j\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^k (n+j)} < \frac{1}{2^k},$$
or
$$\frac{2^{-n}\sqrt{\pi}\, \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n/2 + k/2 + 1/2)\Gamma(n/2 - k/2 + 1)} < 1.\tag{1} $$
Note that $\Gamma(n/2 + k/2 + 1)\Gamma(n/2 - k/2 + 1/2)$ is strictly increasing on $k\in [1, n]$ (taking derivative, using the fact that the digamma function is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$). Also, we have
$$\frac{2^{-n}\sqrt{\pi}\, \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n/2 + 1/2 + 1/2)\Gamma(n/2 - 1/2 + 1)} = 1.$$
Thus, (1) is true.
Second, we prove that $\inf A_k < \inf A_{k+1}$ if $1\le k \le n-1$.
We know that
$$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k \left(\frac{n}{2} - \inf A_k + j\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^k (n+j)} = \frac{1}{2^k}. \tag{2}$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{k+1} \left(\frac{n}{2} - \inf A_k + j\right)}{\prod_{j=1}^{k+1} (n+j)} > \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$
or (using (2))
$$\frac{\frac{n}{2} - \inf A_k + k+ 1}{n + k + 1} > \frac12 $$
or
$$\inf A_k < \frac{k+1}{2}$$
which is true.
We are done.
